# Requiring an Express app in a Mocha Test file starts the server itself

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

**Brief :** While writing tests in Mocha for an Express driven RESTful HTTP API using Supertest, it's known we have to `require` an instance of the express app. However, this require statement is apparently the root cause for an open connection after the tests have finished and cleaned up. This is a bizarre situation and unexpected totally.

**Background :** The repository in question is on GitHub at sakshamsaxena/uzay [1]
The tests are typical in syntax to that recommended by Super Test itself. The `request` creates the server and the callback passed to `expect` closes the server. This was verified by adding `console.log` lines to the library file in `node_modules`. It is verified that all the connections were gracefully closed and tests passed alright. No other notification/warning anything was encountered during this, but Mocha never exited on it's own. I am well aware about the Mocha 4+ behavior and investigated this using WTFNode. On SIGINT, it was noticed[2][3] that an `app` instance is still alive. Naturally, I double checked this by commenting out all tests and running the suite again with WTFNode, only to encounter the exact same message. Right now, the test has no real test, just pending tests, and 2 require statements [4] where one of those is clearly the culprit. What is happening/what am I doing wrong ?

**References :**

[1] : https://github.com/sakshamsaxena/uzay/

[2] :

```
[WTF Node?] open handles:
- File descriptors: (note: stdio always exists)
  - fd 1 (stdio)
  - fd 2 (stdio)
- Servers:
  - :::3000 (HTTP)
    - Listeners:
      - request: app @ 
D:\Personal\uzay\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617
```

[3] : https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode/blob/a080e019f06187aa1e762ac9025bd22430d4129c/index.js#L512

[4] :

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../index.js')
```

**Question :** Requiring the express server isn't supposed to run the server. Without an explicit call to `listen` the server shouldn't have started, but it somehow does. Why does this happen? What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring the root [index.js](https://github.com/sakshamsaxena/uzay/blob/master/index.js#L47) in your tests. `require()` in fact do evaluate the whole js file, thus the `.listen()` call will be run.

You can solve the problem by setting an environment variable that would be set only when running test, say, `process.env.CI`. Then

```
if (!process.env.CI) {
  app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Uzay live on port 3000!')
  })
}
```

Comment: I did have this in the back of my mind, but didn't try it as I never get the `Uzay live on port 3000!` message, which I assumed I'd get if the `listen` is being called. Though what you said did work!

Comment: probably your mocha config overrode the `console.log` output somehow

Comment: Nopes, in fact I've mentioned that I checked server closing by super test by adding `console.log` lines, and it came alright. Tried placing one just before the `listen` too, it came alright too.

Comment: Tried ```app.listen(3000, function () {
  process.env.DEMO = 'DEMO';
  console.log('Uzay live on port 3000!')
})``` and logging this env var in a new `after()` block of a test suite, returned 'DEMO' as expected. Verifies that it hit the callback, but `console` wasn't available to it at that time apparently. Humph! Thanks, this was a great learning experience.

Comment: EDIT: Somehow I developed a blind spot but the `console.log` message for `listen` always used to come (checked previous travis build logs), i just became blind to it I guess. Sorry for the trouble!